# Combine multiple updates to database into one?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, performance, odbc

I have a foreach on 100,000 files and every file will be loaded and then around 10 storedProcedures will be run against the MySQL database with new data.

For every file the connection to the database will open and close.

The problem is that this is very slow. I have tried to make it multithreaded but the Odbc Command will freeze after a short while on open connection or closing connection.

Is there anyway to combine all the updates into a script without changing too much in the code and run one large script on database?

Best Regards

Comment: One why are you opening the connection IN the foreach.  Open once, then foreach, and then Close once.   Multithreaded is not going to help is on the other end is a single hardware write head.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SqlBulkCopy Class . here is some text about that :

[https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEAQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codeproject.com%2FArticles%2F18418%2FTransferring-Data-Using-SqlBulkCopy&ei=eK_tULK_KtHVsgbv3IGACw&usg=AFQjCNGchoZ0gGPZ3Bcnd-8zRfolZ9xfiQ&sig2=pY4JuHwNhGsqLN8Tz5Fspg&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.Yms](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEAQFjAC&url=http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18418/Transferring-Data-Using-SqlBulkCopy&ei=eK_tULK_KtHVsgbv3IGACw&usg=AFQjCNGchoZ0gGPZ3Bcnd-8zRfolZ9xfiQ&sig2=pY4JuHwNhGsqLN8Tz5Fspg&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.Yms)